# Can't export data from SQLite database from my Database from another activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to export data from one activity to a 'csv' file from my Database class (DBHelper.java) but getting the following error:

```
no such table: SQLiteExample.db (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM SQLiteExample.db, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
                                                                               android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: SQLiteExample.db (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM SQLiteExample.db, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

This is my code from my reporting activity (ExportJobCard.java)

```
 public void exportDataBaseIntoCSV() {


    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
    File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/JOBCARDSDATABASE");

    if (!exportDir.exists()) {
        exportDir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(exportDir, "csvfilename.csv");

    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        SQLiteDatabase sql_db = db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor curCSV = sql_db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null);
        csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

        while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
            //Which column you want to export you can add over here...
            String arrStr[] = {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2)};
            csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
        }

        csvWrite.close();
        curCSV.close();
    } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
        Log.e("Error:", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
    }
}
```

If I add the above code directly in my JobCard.class where the user inputs the data and hits save it works,  but I would like to have a different activity for the reporting as I have 2 databases which I need to get reports from.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, cause if it works from the above mentioned activity the surely it should work if i just do from another activity?

This is my database class (DBHelper.java)

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SQLiteExample.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public static final String PERSON_TABLE_NAME = "person";
public static final String PERSON_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String PERSON_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String PERSON_COLUMN_GENDER = "gender";
public static final String PERSON_COLUMN_AGE = "age";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME +
                    "(" + PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    PERSON_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                    PERSON_COLUMN_GENDER + " TEXT, " +
                    PERSON_COLUMN_AGE + " INTEGER)"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertPerson(String name,
                            String gender,
                            int age) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_GENDER, gender);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_AGE, age);

    db.insert(PERSON_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public int numberOfRows() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, PERSON_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
}

public boolean updatePerson(Integer id,
                            String name,
                            String gender,
                            int age) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_GENDER, gender);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_AGE, age);

    contentValues.put(PERSON_JOBDESCRIPTION, jobdescription);
    db.update(PERSON_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}

public Integer deletePerson(Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(PERSON_TABLE_NAME,
            PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}

public Cursor getPerson(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
            PERSON_COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    return res;
}

public Cursor getAllPersons() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME, null );
    return res;
}
}
```

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be from different issues.i faced it before and i try to help you

When you create a sqlite database you should register it into manifest file if you do that but you face it again uninstall and reinstall your app because you database already created so for next version of your database such as new table,because the database already exist your debugger won't create new one or replace new one on old one so although you edited your database but something that already exist in your phone is old one.
so uninstall and re install your app in order to create new sqlite data base .
if you again faced this problem check your syntax it's definitely your syntax error.
and also i think another problem is here

```
"CREATE TABLE " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME +
 "(" + PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    PERSON_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                  PERSON_COLUMN_GENDER + " TEXT, " +
                     PERSON_COLUMN_AGE + " INTEGER)"
```

replace this instead

```
"CREATE TABLE " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME +
                    "(" + PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    PERSON_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                    PERSON_COLUMN_GENDER + " TEXT, " +
                    PERSON_COLUMN_AGE + " INTEGER);"
```

you forgot to add ";"

hope i did help you.

Comment: Hi Thanks,  I had my coding wrong.  Instead of having "DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME" I used " DBHelper.PERSON_TABLE_NAME"

Comment: Thanks for your help!